# Dataframe shows a different type after exporting it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Does anyone know why the dataframe shows a different type after I exported it to excel and then read it?

Before exporting to excel is  `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` type, and after exporting the file is `class 'pandas.core.frame.dataframe'`. Then I found that the tuple would be in a string after exporting it.(But I don't want)

I use both `pd.read_csv` to open the file. Then how to convert it into `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` type. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please create a simple example to recreate the issue?

Comment: please check `https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html` it states, "pandas.DataFrame" is type of class. 
P.S. how do you get the output of `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` without type class?

Comment: @NoobVB I don't know why!! so I'm very confused! 
BTW, if i create a toy dataframe, the type of df is still `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` not `pandas.DataFrame`.

Comment: @Megan `pandas.DataFrame` isn't a type, it's just a handy api to create an object of type `DataFrame` which is described in `pandas/core/frame.py` as `class DataFrame(NDFrame)`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store objects in Excel other than what it can understand. Excel can understand floats and strings. Also some basic types like boolean and date can be stored with help of `Formula` and `NumberFormat` properties. Tuples, lists, dicts etc. are saved as `str(...)`.

As an example:

```
class T():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.v = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.v})'
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Test message ({self.v})'

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':[T(1)],
})

df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False, engine='openpyxl')

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
cell = wb['Sheet1']['A2']
print(
    f'{cell.coordinate=}',
    f'{cell.value=}',
    f'{cell.data_type=}',
    f'{cell.number_format=}',
    sep='\n'
)
wb.close()
```

Output:

```
cell.coordinate='A2'
cell.value='Test message (1)'
cell.data_type='s'
cell.number_format='General'
```

When reading data back, we can only get string representations of complex objects.

As a workaround we could combine `repr` and `eval` for general objects or `ast.literal_eval` for basic structures:

```
df.assign(a=df['a'].map(repr)).to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False)
data = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', converters={0:lambda x: eval(x, {'T': T})})
print(type(data.iloc[0,0]))
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.T'>
```

As for the type issue, I couldn't find `dataframe` in `pandas.core.frame` unless it's a typo in character case. My environment:

```
python 3.8.5
pandas 1.1.3
openpyxl 3.0.10
```